# GWT Vertical Tab

Tags: gwt

I'm curious how to make a vertical tab layout like this :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/708/gmoderator.jpg/

I have been trying to find it in GWT Ref Widget :

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery.html#tabpanel

but didn't find any widget match with my expectation.

Any idea how to implement this? Or maybe a link to any website teach how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Note : I found that the VerticalPanel is supported until GWT 2.1 . After that it's better to create Vertical Panel on the left and create simple panel on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DockPanel with a VerticalPanel on the West for the links/controls
Content at the Center.
Tweak background/border on selection

OR

http://cobogw.googlecode.com/svn/demo/WidgetsDemo.html#VerticalTabPanel